# Exchange ActiveSync device agent strings for Android OS version

Tags: exchange, active-sync

I am creating reports based off of our Exchange ActiveSync logs. One of the fields in the EAS logs is "Device Agent" which tells me the device type and what version of Android the device is on. An example string from this field is:

```
SAMSUNG-GT-N7000/100.20306
```

where the first part before the "/" is the device and the second part is the Android version.

I am sure the version number maps to the Android version since these strings are different than the EAS client strings. An example of and EAS client string is "Android-EAS/2.0" where the number is the version of the ActiveSync client. Devices with those strings report the Android version in another column.

Here are some additional examples of the Android version numbers: 100.202, 100.20303, 100.20304, 100.20305, 100.20306, 100.40003, 100.40004

I was able to leverage this resource for the iOS devices: http://www.onesimplescript.com/2012/06/reporting-on-apple-ios-activesync.html

What I can't figure out is a mapping of the Android versions from these strings to their "friendly" names (KitKat, Ice Cream Sandwich, etc). Are there any resources available that map these numeric OS versions to the OS name?

Comment: Not sure if this question fits this Q&A site, but you might end up building your own hash list.

Comment: Are you sure that version number maps to the Android version, not the version number of the ActiveSync client?

Answer (score 1):

According to the version numbers you've posted, they are the Android version numbers with zero padding. Therefore these can be directly mapped to "friendly" names, which can be found for example on Wikipedia under [Android version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history).

```
100.202   => 2.2   => Froyo
100.20303 => 2.3.3 => Gingerbread
100.20304 => 2.3.4 => Gingerbread
100.20305 => 2.3.5 => Gingerbread
100.20306 => 2.3.6 => Gingerbread
100.40003 => 4.0.3 => Ice Cream Sandwich
100.40004 => 4.0.4 => Ice Cream Sandwich
```

So the remaining should be:

```
100.105   => 1.5   => Cupcake
100.106   => 1.6   => Donut
100.2     => 2.0   => Eclair
100.20001 => 2.0.1 => Eclair
100.201   => 2.1   => Eclair
100.20201 => 2.2.1 => Froyo
100.20202 => 2.2.2 => Froyo
100.20203 => 2.2.3 => Froyo
100.203   => 2.3   => Gingerbread
100.20301 => 2.3.1 => Gingerbread
100.20302 => 2.3.2 => Gingerbread
100.20307 => 2.3.7 => Gingerbread
100.3     => 3.0   => Honeycomb
100.301   => 3.1   => Honeycomb
100.302   => 3.2   => Honeycomb
100.4     => 4.0   => Ice Cream Sandwich
100.40001 => 4.0.1 => Ice Cream Sandwich
100.40002 => 4.0.2 => Ice Cream Sandwich
100.401   => 4.1   => Jelly Bean
100.402   => 4.2   => Jelly Bean
100.403   => 4.3   => Jelly Bean
100.404   => 4.4   => Kit Kat
```